# Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input' - Angular Material Autocomplete, Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I just upgraded my app from Angular 11 to 12 (all the dependencies including angular material). I get the following error when I do the ng serve

```
Error: src/app/components/chips/chips.component.html:19:17 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

19                 [formControl]="itemCtrl"
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The following is my chips.component.ts and chips.component.html

```
import {BaseComponentComponent} from '../basecomponent.component';
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ChipsModel} from '../../models/chips.model';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chips',
    templateUrl: './chips.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chips.component.scss']
})

export class ChipsComponent extends BaseComponentComponent {
...
}
```

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
        <input
                #itemInput
                [formControl]="itemCtrl"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
                title="">
</mat-form-field>
```

I've tried the following fixes which were suggested in similar stackoverflow posts :

Adding these imports to the custom module which is imported in the app.module.ts

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  imports : [
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
exports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ]})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

I am also importing the component class ChipsComponent in the app.module.ts and added it to the ngModule declarations. I still get the error. Any leads on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you please share your `app.module.ts` please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `MatFormFieldModule` as well

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

And add it to your `exports` of `MaterialModule`, there is no need for `imports` array here.

PS: You will need to import `MaterialModule` in your base module.

Comment: I am importing MatFormFieldModule in my material module. Sorry for not including it in the question earlier